# Vuedraggable issues with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Been trying to get Vuedraggable with Laravel to work for a week.  I am new to Vue.

My controller is returning a $testimonials variable into the view.  The $testimonials variable is an array of objects.  I have the following in my view:

```
   <table-draggable :testimonials="{{ $testimonials }}"></table-draggable>
```

I have a TableDraggable Component which is properly registered in my app.  This component has the following code:

```
<template>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quote</th>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Sort</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <draggable v-model="testimonialsNew" draggable=".testimonial" @change="update" handle=".handle">
        <tr v-for="testimonial in testimonialsNew" :key="testimonial.id" class="testimonial">
            <td>
                {{ testimonial.id }}
                <a :href="'testimonials/' + testimonial.id + '/edit'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs mb">Edit</a>
                <form :action="'testimonials/' + testimonial.id" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
                </form>

            </td>
            <td>{{ testimonial.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ testimonial.quote }}</td>
            <td>{{ testimonial.visible }}</td>
            <td>{{ testimonial.order }}</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-arrows my-handle"></i></td>
        </tr>

    </draggable>

    </table>
</template>

<script>
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
    export default {
        components: {
            draggable
        },
        props: ['testimonials'],
        data() {
            return {
                testimonialsNew: this.testimonials,
                csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
            }
        },
        methods: {
            update() {
                this.testimonialsNew.map((testimonial, index) => {
                    testimonial.order = index + 1;
                })
                axios.put('/admin/testimonials/updateAll', {
                    testimonials: this.testimonialsNew
                }).then((response) => {
                    // success message
                })
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

The data is returning but nothing is draggable.  I am 99% sure the error is in these two lines:

```
        <draggable v-model="testimonialsNew" draggable=".testimonial" @change="update" handle=".handle">
        <tr v-for="testimonial in testimonialsNew" :key="testimonial.id" class="testimonial">
```

However, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your draggable class is .handle, but you've used my-handle instead.
Also I would recommend using tag="tbody" on the draggable element for valid html.